# Display Value on Edit

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

This code triggers an email of a new price value in column 14 `onEdit`, but it doesn't give the display value on the sheet. E.g. `15,00,000` is the format in the sheet but it generates the email as `1500000`. where did I go wrong in the below code?

```
function sendEmail(e) {
    var thisSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet(),
        cols = [14],
        ind = cols.indexOf(e.range.columnStart);
    if (thisSheet.getName() !== 'SheetPrice' || ind == -1) return;
    var headers = thisSheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, 6).getValues()[0],
        thisRow = thisSheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, 6).getDisplayValues()[0],
        vehicle = thisRow[3],
        vehicle2 = thisRow[4],
        body = "",
        i = 0; 
   while (i < 6) {
        body += headers[i] + '- ' + thisRow[i] + '\n';
        i++;
    }
if (ind == 0 && e.value) {
       var recipients = "email@email.com",
           subject = "⚫ Price updated ► " +vehicle +" "+vehicle2
           body += "New Price ► "+ e.value + "\n\nabc limited" ;
   }
   MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject,  body, {name: "abc limited"});
}
```

Comment: In the body, you're  using `e.value` and not  the display value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
body += "New Price ► "+ thisSheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart,e.range.columnStart).getDisplayValue() + "\n\nabc limited" ;
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you @cooper. I've been trying even to add the old price somewhere in the body of the email (to compare the price change), is it possible do get the old data and place it in the code? or does it only take the new edited data?